# Verilog assign breaks the synthesis using Icestorm

Tags: fpga, verilog

well, i have this code that is giving a warning "Warning: No clocks found in design", and the FPGA is not doing nothing after flash:

```
module syncRX(clk, signal, detect);
    input clk, signal;
    output reg [7:0] detect = 0;
    reg [7:0] detect_sig = 0;
    
    always @(posedge signal)
     begin
        detect_sig <= detect_sig + 1;
     end
    assign detect = detect_sig;

endmodule // top
```

Seams the problem in the "assign" because with this modification works good:

```
module syncRX(clk, signal, detect);
    input clk, signal;
    output reg [7:0] detect = 0;
    //reg [7:0] detect_sig = 0;
    
    always @(posedge signal)
     begin
        detect <= detect + 1;
     end
    //assign detect = detect_sig;

endmodule // top
```

Anyone knows what is wrong in the first version?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Verilog, `assign` can only be used with `wire` type variables. If you had declared it as `output [7:0] detect` or `output wire [7:0] detect` it would work fine (`wire` is implicitly inferred in the first declaration). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847977/verilog-reg-assignment) is also relevant.

Also bear in mind that initialisation like you have done here is not guaranteed to be synthesisable in an FPGA, and certainly not in an ASIC. You should have a reset input, and use that to reset your `detect_sig` variable to `8'h00`. Note also that you should give defined widths to your assignments, rather than bare `0` or `1`; the tool may complain about truncated widths otherwise, and your intent is clearer.